# Quality control in Seismic Acquisition - shot offset shift

Tags: geophysics, seismology, seismic, data-analysis, data-formats

[image]

I have a problem with seismic data where the minimum offset of the shot is not centered at the nearest receiver, this shift can be for 3 traces 2 or one and maybe more in the two sides !!
So is there any solution for this problem ?